# Why is Track Changes for Libre office not working?

Tags: 22.04

I am a small writer, and i like to have track changes on, but one day i noticed that track changes wasn't tracking the changes. i checked, and it was enabled, just not working. i tried running it in safe mode, that didn't help. any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `soffice --version`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* working. Enable tracking with "Edit - Track Changes - Record". If the changes are not visible, make them visible with "Edit - Track Changes - Show".

Comment: It worked. Thank You so much!!!